# Kashrut of unsalted meat put into freezers

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, kashering-kosherization, blood

In Halacha, as a general rule, when you have meat which is unsalted, you have to soak it into water every 3 days to prevent the blood from making the meat un kosher. My question is, according to Halacha, is it permissible to put unsalted meat into a freezer to preserve it without soaking it? Or would this be halachically insufficient to preserve the meat from being treif?

Comment: This is a machlokes haposkim. I heard the Rabbanut at the start of the state used to rely on this as they were shipping meat from Argentina so they would freeze it and then salt it locally, but now they salt the meat before they freeze it.

Comment: [Here](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/635867/p/88/t/0010278391234/fs/qRQoQCVRRVWH5NUXtknvgu4XpteNXUfdgQeBawDuXfoI/start/0/end/31/c) are the relevant sources (make a free account to see). If I have time I'll see if I can summarize it.

Comment: See https://rabbikaganoff.com/the-crisis-of-unwashed-meat/ under Frozen meat